# Change Background Color of DataGrid cell upon Timer Tick C# forms

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I am currently working on a Program that displays and handles data from a database in C# forms. I have a DataGridView that is empty upon Program Load, and it later filled with data from the database when the user selects items from a ToolStripMenu. I need to be able to alter the background color of a cell in each row, every second. I have instantiated a timer, and set it up to tick every second. I have set up a method event to execute every time the timer ticks (every second), shown below:

```
  void _timer_0_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

In this method I would like to be able to color the "status" cell of each row in the DataGrid to either red or green, based upon if the Status is good or bad.

Here is some pseudocode in the method illustrating what I would like to do:

```
  void _timer_0_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      bool isDataStable = //code to determine if stable on my end
      if(isDataStable == true)
        {
            DataGrid.Row[Index].Column["Status"].BackColor = Green;
        }
      else
        {
            DataGrid.Row[Index].Column["Status"].BackColor = Red;
        }
   }
```

Every DataGridView row/column edit example I've seen has to use an event handler based upon the DataGridView, how can I implement the timer while also editing the GridView in real time?

Thanks

Comment: Where does index come from?  What is it supposed to represent?

Comment: Having a timer checking an undetermined number of rows each second is a bad design. As the data will only change after the user ends the row edit that's the moment to check if the data is valid and color the status cell.

Comment: The `DataGridView` class has a `Rows` property and each `DataGridViewRow` has a `Cells` property and each `DataGridViewCell` has a `Style` property which has a `BackColor` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudo-code is close - just use the proper properties:

```
void _timer_0_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      bool isDataStable = //code to determine if stable on my end
      if(isDataStable == true)
        {
            DataGrid.Rows[Index].Cells["Status"].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
      else
        {
            DataGrid.Rows[Index].Cells["Status"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
   }
```